# Atmel Studio 7 setting int = 0, returns 257

Tags: c++, int, atmel, atmelstudio

When ever i try to set my index int = 0, it becomes 257.
I tried the following test code in visual studio, where it functions perfectly.

```
int main() {

int index = 0;
int Data[24] = { 1, 0, 1, 1 };

//Await the first 4 start bits.
do
{
    while (0) //awaiting high on a pin
    {}
    if (Data[index] == 0) //checking other pin for high
        index++;
    else {
        index = 0; //Becomes 257???
    }
} while (index < 4);
}
```

I'm trying to check if the first bit is as we expected. I turned off optimisation for the project, so i can simulate my code.

Here's the tricky part. For some reason [index becomes 257](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0wqB.png). I've also took a peek at the assembly code, while running the debugger. The following two lines, changes index to 256, and then 257.

```
            index = 0; //Becomes 257
00000156  STD Y+2,R1        Store indirect with displacement 
00000157  STD Y+1,R1        Store indirect with displacement
   } while (index < 4);
```

It only happens when index is already 0. (R1 is 1 at this point).

Why does this happen, and how can i avoid it?